# Set the list value using linq

Tags: linq, class, c#-3.0

Hi I want to set the value in the list of objects that matches the given condition in the where clause.Is it possible?
Other work around is to get the list of objects using where clause and then iterate using for Or foreach loop and update the value.

```
listOfRequestAssigned.Where(x => x.RequestedNumber == CurrentRequest);
```

I have list listOfRequestAssigned of objects and want to update some propery of the objects that match my search criteria.

```
class Request
 {
 bool _requestCompleted;
   int _requestedNumber;
     public int RequestedNumber 
    {
        get { return _requestedNumber; }
        set { _requestedNumber = value; }
    }
    public bool RequestCompleted
    {
        get { return _requestCompleted; }
        set { _requestCompleted = value; }
    }
 }
```

I want to update RequestCompleted property of all objects that match criteria using Linq

Comment: be carefull, in the Where, use == for comparaison ;) and yes, you can use Linq for do your work in one line of code

Comment: Yes i made the change there was exception while compiling ;) thanks for help @  Xaruth

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ForEach` in Linq

```
listOfRequestAssigned.Where(x => x.RequestedNumber == CurrentRequest).ToList().ForEach(x => x.RequestCompleted = true);
```

if you have more than one update to do,

```
listOfRequestAssigned.Where(x => x.RequestedNumber == CurrentRequest).ToList().ForEach(x =>  { x.RequestCompleted = true; x.OtherProperty = value; } );
```

`Where(...)` give you a query, not a `Request` or a `List<Request>`. Use `FirstOrDefault()` if you want to have one (or 0) result, or `ToList()` if you want to have a list of results on wich you can use `ForEach()`.

Comment: There is no foreach after where condition.I have checked the code.It does not work

Comment: @ Xaruth got it my mistake.Yes thats possible.This one also works

Comment: edited just before your comment. Use .ToList() in order to convert query in list that you can work with.

Answer (score 2):

In general Linq is a query- not an update tool, but you can use a `foreach`:

```
var currentRequests =  listOfRequestAssigned
    .Where(x => x.RequestedNumber == CurrentRequest);
foreach(var req in currentRequests)
{
    req.RequestCompleted = true;
}
```

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter Sir.I wanted to know if that was possible through linq.Foreach is definitely the option.Thank you sir.. :)

Comment: @Tim is there a way to update each element of the list but in a signle line. Instead of writing a painy foreach(var req in currentRequests)
{
    req.RequestCompleted = true;
}

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specific collection of type List, you can just use ForEach and a conditional set:

```
listOfRequestAssigned.Foreach(x => { if (x.RequestedNumber == CurrentRequest) x.RequestCompleted = true;}});
```

If you had a more generic collection IEnumerable, you can use Select in Linq to build a projection where property will be set as desired (original collection will be left untouched!):

```
listOfRequestAssigned
.Where(x => x.RequestedNumber == CurrentRequest)
.Select(x => { x.RequestCompleted = true; return x; })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to assign boolean value by following on comparing time. This is the very simplest and smart way for bool property.

```
    listOfRequestAssigned.ForEach(x => x.RequestCompleted = x.RequestedNumber 
    == CurrentRequest);
```